# Install and run yarn inside the docker container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, yarnpkg

I have docker build which works fine. But i want to install version specific yarn inside the container(it is the task) and run it after building, cause i dont want rebuild the container for install new dependecies. Current Dockerfile and docker-compose.yml

Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:16.17.0-alpine 

WORKDIR /front

COPY package.json .

RUN yarn install

COPY . .

CMD ["yarn", "start"]

ENV PORT 8000

EXPOSE $PORT
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.8"

services: 
  frontend: 
    build: 
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      args:
        NODE_MAJOR: '16.17.0'
        YARN_VERSION: '1.22.19'
    image: front-dev:1.0.0
    container_name: front-dev
    volumes:
      - .:/front:cached
      - ./node_modules:/front/node_modules
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    env_file:
      - .env
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=development
    cpu_shares: 512
volumes:
  node_modules:
```

Comment: "I dont want rebuild container each time when depencies will updated", this is not the way containers should be used.

Comment: @Pino Sry, a bit incorrectly formulated. Already edited my question

Comment: OK, I've read the update, but I confirm: this is not the way containers should be used. If your application changes (including a change in dependencies only) you should build a new image and distribute it in all your environment (test, UAT, production...).

Comment: @Pino I dont have enough qualification and credit to prove it for person who give me that task) btw i tried

Comment: Your `volumes:` block is hiding almost everything in the image; it seems like this particular setup is trying to run code that exists mostly on the host, but "in Docker".  Do you actually need Docker here; can you install the extremely specific tool version you need directly on the host instead?

Comment: @DavidMaze Goal of this code it is just for backend developers have opportunity to check current UI without set up local environment just run two make-commands inside the repo

Comment: It seems like that same Makefile could download Node and Yarn and install them in a local tree, without requiring Docker and its complications.  That would also give you a clear Make target; you can download Node iff `./node-$(NODE_VERSION)/bin/node` exists.  Elsewhere in container space, the Kubebuilder tool for building Kubernetes extensions also essentially works this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install yarn with apk(equivalent for apk in alpine). Move yarn commands from Dockerfile to docker-compose.yml(like below)

Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:16.17.0-alpine 

WORKDIR /frontend

COPY package.json yarn.lock ./

RUN set -eux \
    & apk add \
        --no-cache \
        yarn

ENV PORT 8000

EXPOSE $PORT
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.8"

services: 
  front: 
    build: 
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      args:
        NODE_MAJOR: '16.17.0'
        YARN_VERSION: '1.22.19'
    image: front-dev:1.0.0
    container_name: front-dev
    volumes:
      - .:/frontend
      - ./node_modules:/frontend/node_modules
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    env_file:
      - .env
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=development
    cpu_shares: 512
    command: 'yarn start'
volumes:
  node_modules:
```

P.S It is make building process much more faster.

Comment: copying the package.json and lock is pointless.